# Setup Account compulsory field for different application

Tags: account

A user want some  standard fields in Account to be set as compulsory field in the page layout but that field also used in different application but not as required field.If we setup validation rule, it will impact other back end application.How to setup for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by making the field required in the page layout.  Fields defined as required via a page layout will only be required via that specific layout and won't affect back end processes.  Here's the relevant [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutoverview.htm&language=en_US)

To make the field required via the layout, you need to:

1. Edit the appropriate layout (likely the Account layout in your case)
2. Click on the wrench icon next to the field you want to make required.
3. Select the required checkbox.
4. Save the layout.

Here is a screenshot.[image]